# I want update the listed data in tableview through swipe trailing

Tags: swift

```
// here is 2 view controller

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var arrname = NSMutableArray()
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let dict = arrname[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary
        cell.txtFldName.text = dict!["name"] as? String
        cell.txtFldEmail.text = dict!["email"] as? String
        cell.txtFldPhone.text = dict!["phone"] as? String
        return cell
    }
    
    // this swipe editing
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        arrname.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
        tblView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        
        let action =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "edit") { [weak self]
            (action, view, completionHandler) in
            
            self?.handlerfun(index: indexPath.row)
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        
        action.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    }
    
    private func handlerfun(index:Int){
        let dict = arrname[index]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "data"),
            object: dict
        )
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}


// here is first ViewController from where I need to update
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldName:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldEmail:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldPhone:UITextField!
    var namearr = NSMutableArray()
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(add),
            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "data"),
            object: nil
        )
    }
    
    @objc func add(notification:Notification) {
        if let data = notification.object as? NSMutableDictionary {
            txtFldName.text = data["name"] as! String
            txtFldPhone.text = data["phone"] as! String
            txtFldEmail.text = data["email"] as! String
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend not using notification center. I've always used closures or delegates. Notification center is way too much trouble imo

Comment: @AdrianMole yes it's a mistake by me, thanks for your comment, I removed that comment. thanks for your responsibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// replace your private func handlerfun with this code :-

 private func handleMarkAsEdit(_ index:Int) {
        let dict = arrData[index]
        let newDict = NSMutableDictionary()
        newDict.setValue(dict, forKey: "oldDict")
        newDict.setValue(index, forKey: "index")
               NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "pass"), object: newDict)
               self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
           }
// add this in second vc after viewDidLoad 
        if index != -1 {
            arrData.replaceObject(at: index, with: dict)
            tableVw.reloadData()
        }

//ADD this code in first vc after set value in dictionary 
 if index != -1 {
                    vc.arrData = self.array
                    vc.index = self.index
                    vc.dict = dataDict
                    index = -1
                } else {
                    array.add(dataDict)
                    vc.arrData = self.array
                
                }
// replace add function in first vc with this code 
    @objc func add(notification:Notification){
        if let data = notification.object as? NSMutableDictionary {
            let oldDict = data["oldDict"] as! NSMutableDictionary
            validateNameTxtFld.text = oldDict["name"] as? String ?? ""
            validateEmailTxtFld.text = oldDict["email"] as? String ?? ""
            validatePhoneTxtFld.text = oldDict["phone"] as? String ?? ""
            index = data["index"] as? Int ?? 0
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.